# How to set a unique WordPress theme for different pages?

Tags: themes

I am new to wordpress. I am trying to build a custon website based on it. I know some php and quite good html \ css \ js. I wanted to know if it's possible to set a uinque theme for different pages?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with page templates. See -

- Codex : [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)
- Codex : [Creating Your Own Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)